# laravel search results grouping

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a car rental website built with Laravel and when I search for a car I want the results to be grouped by brand for example (mercedes, ford, bmw). and when I click on "mercedes" for example then it has to display just " mercedes" cars in another page.

In other word I don't want to display all cars in one page. In first page I want grouped results. And when I click on "mercdes" then a new get request will be sent to get only "mercedes" cars in separate page.

I used `groupBy()` collection helper to group the results and display it in the first page. But the problem is the second step. I thought about using the same database query as the first except adding constraint for example (`where brand = mercedes`) to get only mercedes cars.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Please post the query/ies you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a special formula for that is **query builder** . You can easily make your query by using this **query builder**. you can make a query by using the following query

**`$users = DB::table('cars')
                ->groupBy('brand')
                ->get();`**

you can see the full documentation of query builder [Laravel Query Builder Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: but this for the first step to get the grouped results. What about the seconde step when you click on "mercedes" and get "mercedes" cars ?